# Class 'CLSID_CorSymWriter' could not be created: Access is denied

Tags: .net, iis-7

i keep getting this error. not sure what it is. this is what i have done so far. am working on VISTA and have IIS7. i created a new site and have a directory with my aspx files attached to it. then i converted one of the subfolders to an application. But for some reason when i try to turn on that application (right click browse) i get the following error -

Class 'CLSID_CorSymWriter' could not be created: Access is denied.

why is access denied. this application works on parent system but not here. so i know its some permission issue or some component i havent installed yet.

any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem and solved it by altering the machine.config present in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\CONFIG folder.

Set userName and password in the processModel section to admin user and password of the admin user.

Answer (score 0):

Not encountered this error before, but an Internet search led to someone on another ([hyphenated](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_21629545.html)) web site suggesting the following:

From a command prompt, change directory to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322 (or whichever version) and then enter two commands:

1. regsvr32.exe diasymreader.dll
2. regsvr32.exe mscordbi.dll

Comment: i have V1.1.4322 but I also have v3.5. So not sure if this command is only for v1.1 or can be for later versions too

Comment: I think I'd go for the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 directory if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just might have found a solution that worked for me. For some reason the registry was missing one specific key and its subkeys. All I had to do is import a .REG file exported from another machine where this error was not occurring. The contents of the .REG file I used are these:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0AE2DEB0-F901-478b-BB9F-881EE8066788}]
@="NDP SymWriter"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0AE2DEB0-F901-478b-BB9F-881EE8066788}\InprocServer32]
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
@="mscoree.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0AE2DEB0-F901-478b-BB9F-881EE8066788}\InprocServer32\2.0.50727]
@="2.0.50727"
"ImplementedInThisVersion"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0AE2DEB0-F901-478b-BB9F-881EE8066788}\ProgID]
@="CorSymWriter_SxS"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0AE2DEB0-F901-478b-BB9F-881EE8066788}\Server]
@="diasymreader.dll"
```

Keep in mind you might need to change the permissions on the registry key in questions before you import the file (you might even need to change the registry key owner before changing the permissions!)

Use at your own risk; touching the registry (especially *this* part of the registry) is always delicate business, but at least it worked for me without any visible downside.